# Second and third drives

Tags: installation

I might be reformatting my windows installation and installing Ubuntu. I have a huge number of files that need to go over. I also have D: and E: hard drives to which I can transfer those files.

My question is: how will installing Ubuntu on my C: drive affect those drives. Will those be mountable as well? Will I be able to use them "out of the box" as soon as I'm finished installing?

The file system on the drives is the one that's not FAT32 I can't remember what its called -- NTSC?

Answer (score 0):

Your C: drive will be erased, but as long as you don't touch the other drives, you'll be able to access them out of the box. The file system is called NTFS.